# Weird Ito Transformation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Suppose that $X_t$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued semi-martingale with decomposition $X_0+A_t+M_t$, where $A_t$ is finite variation and $M_t$ is a local martingale.   What would be the semi-martingale decomposition for
$$
e^{k\cdot X_t}X_t,
$$
where $k>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: apply ito's formula on the $f(x,t) = xe^{kx}$, where $x = X_{t}$ and then simply split the $dt$ parts and the stochastic parts

Comment: $X_t$ is a semi-martingale, there need not be a "dt" part...

Comment: What do you mean? dt parts will belong to the new $A_t$ representation. Your "$X_t$ is a semi-martingale" statement is irrelevant

Comment: Oh you mean the finite variation part?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that

Comment: Oh alright.  Though, I think this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I believe that this website isn't supposed to serve as a homework solving place. For educational purposes it is better to give hints rather than the solution, don't you think? Definition of "answer to a question" is not necessarily a solution to the problem. I opted for this type of answer under the assumption that you did not just blatantly ask others to solve your homework question (even though you did) but maybe wanted some help/hits to lead you in the right direction

Comment: It wasn;t a homework question, but something that came up during independent reading.